# SDL: Render Texture on top of another texture

Tags: c++, textures, rendering, sdl, blit

i am having trouble with the following:

I need to render a texture on top of another texture and then render that main texture.
For example I have the blue rectangle texture, and I want to draw red rectangles on top of this blue rect. However i want them to restrict the render only on this rectangle. Like the following image:
[image]

I read something about texture blit between them or something like that but im not sure if this is posible.

My code looks like this:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(ren,bluetexture,NULL,dBLUErect);
SDL_RenderCopy(ren,redtexture,NULL,dREDrect);
SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
```

Any one knows about how to do this in SDL 2.0? thats what Im using by the way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mars answer  didnt work because it drew a black texture and nothing could be drawn on that.

But THIS WORKS!:

```
SDL_Texture* auxtexture = SDL_CreateTexture(ren, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 500, 500);

//change the rendering target

SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(auxtexture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
SDL_SetRenderTarget(ren, auxtexture);

//render what we want
triangle->render(ren); //render my class triangle e.g


//change the target back to the default and then render the aux

SDL_SetRenderTarget(ren, NULL); //NULL SETS TO DEFAULT
SDL_RenderCopy(ren, auxtexture, NULL, canvas->drect);
SDL_DestroyTexture(auxtexture);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Some tips for future readers. Always make sure you initialize your `SDL_Renderer` with the `SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE` flag to support render targets. Also, never try to use a `SDL_Texture` that was created from a `SDL_Surface` using the `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` function. It just won't work.

Comment: @JustinSkiles I'm glad someone noticed the lack of SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE, for a brief moment I thought either I'd gone crazy or the api had suddenly changed to allow all renderers to render straight to render target textures.

Comment: I couldn't understand what happens here. Please, somebody, explain? What is the triangle->render(). How does this function work, and where is the code for this function? What is SDL function call inside this function?

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to create your texture on which you want to draw with `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET` flag. So create `back` texture like this:

```
back = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 50, 50);
```

Then, when calling drawing functions, you need to set the `back` texture as the target, like so:

```
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, back);
```

Then you draw what you want, and after that you change the target to null:

```
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
```

And render `back` texture:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, back, NULL, &some_rect);
```